# python pandas index dataframe using a dict

Tags: python, select, dictionary, indexing, pandas

Consider having a dataframe with columns 'A', 'B' and 'C'.

I would like to select rows from the dataframe using a dict of the form {'A':1, 'B':2}. This should give me all the rows where A=1 and B=2.

Also the dict is changing dynamically so I don't know in advance which columns need to be queried. It might be {'A':1, 'C':2} at another iteration.

Comment: can you upload your sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.groupby.filter()` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# =============================
np.random.seed()
A = np.random.randint(1, 5, 100)
B = np.random.randint(1, 5, 100)
C = np.random.randint(1, 5, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=A,B=B,C=C))
print(df)

    A  B  C
0   3  4  4
1   2  2  4
2   2  2  4
3   3  1  1
4   2  4  2
5   3  3  2
6   1  1  3
7   3  3  3
8   4  4  4
9   2  4  3
.. .. .. ..
90  3  1  3
91  3  2  3
92  1  1  1
93  1  2  3
94  3  2  2
95  2  4  1
96  4  2  3
97  4  2  4
98  1  2  3
99  1  4  3

[100 rows x 3 columns]


# processing
# =====================
my_dict = {'A':1, 'B':2}

df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda row: (row.A == my_dict['A']) & (row.B == my_dict['B']))

    A  B  C
41  1  2  1
43  1  2  2
53  1  2  4
67  1  2  1
93  1  2  3
98  1  2  3
```

Comment: In my case the dict is changing dynamically so this is not an option. I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I met something similar. This is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(A=(1, 2, 3, 4), B=(5, 6, 7, 8), C=(9, 10, 11, 12),
         D=(1, 2, 3, 4)))

search = dict(A=2, B=6)
search_string = ','.join(map(str, search.values()))
df['merged'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(map(str, [getattr(x, col) for col in search])),
    axis=1)
df = df[df['merged'] == search_string].drop('merged', axis=1).set_index(
    [k for k in search])

print(df)
```

Here the `search` dict can be whatever you want